# Is it possible to type string template?

Tags: purescript

So that it would be able to assign a string value that only composed of a typed template values.

```
tStr = "2000:80" -- "Int:Int"
tStr = "2000:AAA" -- "Int:String" - that would be an error
```

For example typescript support this:

```
type TemplateS = `${number}:{number}`
const tStr: TemplateS = "2000:80"
```

Comment: No, it is not..

Comment: Is it a bad idea, not idiomatic?

Comment: As always, it entirely depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible but it would not be practical and may significantly increase compilation time. You would have to make use of `Symbol`, `RowList`, `Append`, and type classes.

TypeScript wants to retrofit types to stringly-typed JavaScript APIs because it is a JavaScript superlanguage. PureScript is different. It prefers the creation of new APIs with a strong type design from conception.

If you want a pair of types use `Tuple`. For example: `Tuple 1 2 :: Tuple Int Int` or `Tuple 1 "2" :: Tuple Int String`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.